# Mesh not mirroring correctly

Tags: mirror

I'm new to blender and am running into issues with mirroring.  I am trying to mirror the truck's cabin over the z axis but it's mirroring over on the other side of the vehicle. I tried flipping it and moving the origin.  How do i fix this?

[image][image]

Comment: Hi :) First thing, upper right hand side of the 3D viewport, Properties Panel, Transform > Rotation > Y axis = 90°. This should be set to zero. To do that : in Object mode, select your model then open the Apply menu, Ctrl + A and choose the Rotation and Scale option. Now you can change to the X axis in the Mirror modifier. Note that the modifier uses the objects origin ( the orange dot ) as its axis center so if need be move your model a little in the X direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First apply rotation using ctrl + a then move your 3d cursor to right edge of the cabin and set the cabin's origin as the 3d cursor(object -> set origin -> origin to 3d cursor).Also move up your boolean modifier above the mirror modifier.